# How do I wire a tactile switch to a SPST momentary push button switch?

Tags: switches, wiring

Okay, so I have a tactile switch, it's about 6x6x6mm. I also have a SPST Momentary Push Button Switch. I'll leave the links to them from Amazon.

[https://www.amazon.com/URTONE-Momentary-Stainless-Suitable-Mounting/dp/B01FKXRYVE?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FKXRYVE)
[https://www.amazon.com/QTEATAK-Momentary-Tactile-Button-Switch/dp/B07VSNN9S2/ref=sr_1_8?crid=2IBOJBEQ7KB1W&keywords=tactile%2Bswitch&qid=1672912488&sprefix=tactile%2Bswitch%2Caps%2C155&sr=8-8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VSNN9S2)

And here's what they look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a diagram of how I have to connect the momentary button switches to a MOSFET board.

https://vapoven.com/battery-powered-induction-heater-wiring-diagram/

So I need to figure out how can I circuit the tactile switch to the other momentary button switch. Basically make it a slave to the other button. I don't know if for each button I should just connect them to the TRIG/PWM and VIN+ on the MOSFET board or if there is a way to connect the tactile switch to the other button.

Edit: Wanted to clarify the purpose of these buttons is to turn the induction heater on and also turn on a green LED to let you know when the induction heater is on and off when the button is released.

Comment: What do you mean "make it a slave to the other button"?  If you connect them in parallel then either one will do the same thing. If you connect them in series then both have to be pressed simultaneously to do "the thing" whatever that is. In both cases, it is symmetrical and equitable, neither button has a "master/slave" relationship to the other.

Comment: Oh, what I meant was both switches are meant to turn the induction heater on and also turn on a green LED to let you know the IH is currently on and off when the button(s) are released.

Comment: Ok, so I actually just looked at the Amazon page for that SPST momentary push button switch and someone asked a question does it matter which wire goes to which terminal? And someone answered it doesn't really matter which wire goes to which terminal because the switch functions by being open all the time. When pressed the circuit is now closed. So it doesn't really matter which wires go to which terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect the switches in parallel then they'll both do the same thing (assuming they're momentary and only one is  pressed at once). If both are pressed at the same time it won't hurt anything but the second switch to be pressed or the first to be released will have no effect.

It doesn't matter which wire goes to which  terminal on the panel switch.  The other (tact) switch has 2 pairs of pins (total of 4), each one of the pair is shorted internally to the other. But if you use corner pins you'll not get it wrong.